# Google App Script - copy and increment Date to next row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column with date

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(2,1));
```

give me the same date as previous row.

The above code works well for values and formulas, but not date.

How do I copy it such that it replicate the dragging behaviour, i.e. 11/6/2021 become 12/6/2021.

I have already formatted it as date, I can increment it by manually dragging the cell in UI, but I can't use copyTo in app script to achieve the same result.

Comment: You can apply `Format` > `Number` > `Date` for the column and it will increment dates with dragging. Probably you need to tweak the date format (`Format` > `Number` > `More formats` > `More date and time formats` ), since GAS uses USA format `month/day/year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Apps Script`, you need to convert to cell values to `Date format` in order to increment the date as google sheet is using `Java Script` by adding customize function, below is the way you can add `Day + 1` in the next row using Javascript `new Date()` method:

```
function increRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = new Date( ss.getRange(1,1).getValue());
  ss.getRange(2,1).setValue(new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)));
}
```

[image]

You may try another method `autofill` which perform as human action to fill `Range("A2:A4")`, if you preferred:

```
function autoFill() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  spreadsheet.getRange(2,1).autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange(2,1,3,1), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
 
};
```

Comment: I have already formatted as date prior to this. Problem is I can increment that by manually dragging the cell in UI, but I can't use CopyTo in app script to achieve the same result. Is there no other way around this?

Comment: Ya, it can be achieve also, see my edited answer, accept the answer if helping you :)

Comment: not accepting, waiting for other to answer. I would figure that copyTo will work too, and if not, a justification to be given.

Comment: Do you really understand what is the meaning of copy? it will be impossible to copy and paste different value, from which language you can achieve such outcome, I never see it in my life, not even VBA.

Comment: Glad you are happy with it :)